# Product of strictly stationary time series processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Suppose ${Y_{1t}}, {Y_{2t}},\cdots, {Y_{Nt}}$ are $N$ distinct strictly stationary time series processes, where $t\in Z$, and $Z$ is the set of all integers. We further assume that the $N$ time series processes ${Y_{1t}}, {Y_{2t}},\cdots, {Y_{Nt}}$ are independent.  Define a new time series process ${Z_t}$ by putting $$Z_t =\prod_{k=1}^{N}{Y_{kt}},\ t\in Z.$$

> Is the new time series process ${Z_t}$ weakly stationary? Explain.

From what I understand, we can show that this process is weakly stationary if we can show the mean and autocovariance do not vary with time.

Given the independence and stationarity of the distinct time series processes, it is straightforward to show that $E\left(Z_t\right)$ is time-independent, satisfying one part of the stationarity.

How can I show that the autocovariance is time-independent?

Comment: Why is $E(Z_t) = 0$? Is $E(Y_{it}) = 0$ for all $i=1, \ldots, N$?

Comment: That was a typo on my part, I should have said that we can show $E(Z_t)$ is time-independent.

Comment: Ok I modified my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By independence, you have
\begin{align}
E(Z_t Z_s) &= E\left(\prod_{k=1}^N Y_{kt} \prod_{k=1}^N Y_{ks} \right)\\
&= E\left(Y_{1t}Y_{1s}Y_{2t}Y_{2s} \cdots Y_{Nt}Y_{Ns} \right)\\
&= E\left(Y_{1t}Y_{1s}\right)E\left(Y_{2t}Y_{2s}\right)\cdots E\left(Y_{Nt}Y_{Ns}\right)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^N E(Y_{kt}Y_{ks})
\end{align}
Now if each $Y_{kt}$ is stationary $E(Y_{kt}Y_{ks}) = E_k(t-s)$. Moreover, $\mu = E(Z_t)$ does not depend on time and therefore
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Z_t,Z_s )= \prod_{k=1}^N E_k(t-s) - \mu^2,
$$ 
which shows that $E(Z_t Z_s)$ is a function of $t-s$ only and therefore that $Z_t$ is weakly stationary.

Comment: Why is it that $E(Y_{kt},Y_{ks})=E_k(t-s)$ if $Y_{kt}$ is stationary?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity. The autocorrelation function is independent of time $t$ but only on the time distance between the points. The index $k$ is just because we don't know whether the processes are independent (among $k$) and therefore used to distinguish. I could have written $E(Y_{kt}Y_{ks}) = F_k(t-s)$ for some function $F_k$ which represents the autocorrelation of the $k$-th process.